# Filtering duplicates out of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
class MyObj {
    int Id;
    string Name;
    string Location;
}

IEnumerable<MyObj> list;
```

I want to convert list to a dictionary like this:

```
list.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

but it tells me I have duplicate keys. How can I keep only the first item for each key?

Comment: First, you need to tell us what you want the code to do if there are two objects with the same name but different IDs or locations.

Comment: Sorry, too early in the morning. I'll shut up now. :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suppose the easiest way would be to group by key and take the first element of each group:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.name).Select(g => g.First()).ToDictionary(x => x.name);
```

Or you could use `Distinct` if your objects implement `IEquatable` to compare between themselves by key:

```
// I'll just randomly call your object Person for this example.
class Person : IEquatable<Person> 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return Name == other.Name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return base.Equals(obj as Person);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

...

list.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Or if you don't want to do that (maybe because you normally want to compare for equality in a different way, so `Equals` is already in use) you could make a custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer` just for this case:

```
class PersonComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;

        if (y == null)
            return false;

        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

...

list.Distinct(new PersonComparer()).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
list.Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672412/eliminate-duplicates-ienumerable/1672464#1672464 - you'll need to ensure that your objects implement IEquatable

Answer (score 5):

You could also create your own Distinct extension overload method that accepted a Func<> for choosing the distinct key:

```
public static class EnumerationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource,TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector)
    {
        KeyComparer comparer = new KeyComparer(keySelector);

        return source.Distinct(comparer);
    }

    private class KeyComparer<TSource,TKey> : IEqualityComparer<TSource>
    {
        private Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector;

        public DelegatedComparer(Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector)
        {
            this.keySelector = keySelector;
        }

        bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(TSource a, TSource b)
        {
            if (a == null && b == null) return true;
            if (a == null || b == null) return false;

            return keySelector(a) == keySelector(b);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(TSource obj)
        {
            return keySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Apologies for any bad code formatting, I wanted to reduce the size of the code on the page. Anyway, you can then use ToDictionary:

```
 var dictionary = list.Distinct(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks, though KeyComparer should probably be public (since it can be used with any IEqualityComparer APIs)

Answer (score 2):

Could make your own perhaps? For example:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToDictionary2<TKey, TValue>(
        this IEnumerable<TValue> subjects, Func<TValue, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
        foreach(var subject in subjects)
        {
            var key = keySelector(subject);
            if(!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                dictionary.Add(key, subject);
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}

var dictionary = list.ToDictionary2(x => x.Name);
```

Haven't tested it, but should work. (and it should probably have a better name than ToDictionary2 :p)

Alternatively, you can implement a `DistinctBy` method, for example like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSubject> DistinctBy<TSubject, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TSubject> subjects, Func<TSubject, TValue> valueSelector)
{
    var set = new HashSet<TValue>();
    foreach(var subject in subjects)
        if(set.Add(valueSelector(subject)))
            yield return subject;
}

var dictionary = list.DistinctBy(x => x.Name).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: There is really no need to implement such things which are already there.

Comment: But it isn't already there? And if adding such a method will make my code work in a cleaner way, I would do it :)

Comment: IMO it sure is cleaner than the Joining and IEqualityComparer suggestions that are here at least...

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the ToDictionary extension method does not support multiple values with the same key.  One solution is to write a version which does and use that instead.

```
public static Dictionary<TKey,TValue> ToDictionaryAllowDuplicateKeys<TKey,TValue>(
  this IEnumerable<TValue> values,
  Func<TValue,TKey> keyFunc) {
  var map = new Dictionary<TKey,TValue>();
  foreach ( var cur in values ) {
    var key = keyFunc(cur);
    map[key] = cur;
  }
  return map;
}
```

Now converting to a dictionary is straight forward

```
var map = list.ToDictionaryAllowDuplicateKeys(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: The problem is that the *dictionary* does not support multiple keys. So this code will throw an exception anyway. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @Stefan, The [] operator on dictionary will work in both the case where the key does and does not exist. In the case where it does exist it will simply replace the previous value with the new expression.  It is the equivalent of a Put style operation vs. an Add

Comment: That will result in the opposite behaviour though. He will end up with the last item instead of the first.

Comment: @Svish, the OP didn't specify which behavior he wanted, it could easily be converted to do it the other way

Answer (score 1):

The following will work if you have different instances of MyObj with the same value for the Name property. It will take the first instance found for each duplicate (sorry for the obj - obj2 notation, it is just sample code):

```
list.SelectMany(obj => new MyObj[] {list.Where(obj2 => obj2.Name == obj.Name).First()}).Distinct();
```

**EDIT**: Joren's solution is better as it does not create unnecessary arrays in the process.