# Remove doubles from structs array

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I know 2 ways to remove doubles from an array of objects that support explicit comparing:

1. Using HashSet constructor and
2. Using LINQ's Distinct().

How to remove doubles from array of structs, comparing array members by a single field only? In other words, how to write the predicate, that could be used by Distinct().

Regards,

Comment: by "double", do you mean "duplicates"? or `System.Double`?

Comment: also; you can't really "remove" items from an array, since an array is fixed size... you could overwrite them, of course..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you *could* implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` to pick out that field and use that for equality testing and hashing... or you could use [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) which is in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com).

Of course, you don't have to take a dependency on MoreLINQ really - you can implement it very simply:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
     Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    // TODO: Implement null argument checking :)

    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how about *IComparable<TheStructInQuestion>*? Would that have worked too?

Comment: @astander: No, because `Distinct` etc deal in terms of equality, not sorting. In particular, to use something like a hash table, you need to be able to get a hash code for any particular value.

Comment: MK, I see. Would have guessed that that would be used in the equality comparison, but very good to know. X-) +1

Comment: @Danny: Yes, but that's not the case here, is it? Basically `EqualityComparer<T>` will use the overrides of GetHashCode/Equals if the type doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`. The implementation inherited from ValueType will work, but it's not optimal - you at least want to override GetHashCode and Equals... and at that point you might as well implement `IEquatable<T>` and avoid all the boxing.

Comment: Why to add null-checking? I've just seen MoreLINQ code. I think the exception, thrown by .ThrowIfNull() is the same as exception, thrown by CLR when trying to dereference source or func. Am I wrong?

Comment: @noober: No, it'll throw a NullReferenceException which won't make it clear what's going on at all - whereas you can throw ArgumentNullException, stating which argument was null. Also, it's generally a good idea to validate arguments *before* you do anything else - otherwise you might find that the method only fails half way through, leaving the system in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably just loop:

```
var values = new HashSet<FieldType>();
var newList = new List<ItemType>();
foreach(var item in oldList) {
    if(hash.Add(item.TheField)) newList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: `HashSet<T>.Add` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` as a comparer(if not specified), so it's the same as `var result = arr.Distinct();` which is also using the default comparer, isn't it?

Comment: @Danny - yes, but the `Distinct` in the question is comparing the **parent instance** *itself*; in the code above I'm comparing a *single property* of the parent instance.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ answer has been published before. I am copying from Richard Szalay's answer here: [Filtering duplicates out of an IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672412/50079)

```
public static class EnumerationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Distinct<TSource,TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector)
    {
        KeyComparer comparer = new KeyComparer(keySelector);

        return source.Distinct(comparer);
    }

    private class KeyComparer<TSource,TKey> : IEqualityComparer<TSource>
    {
        private Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector;

        public DelegatedComparer(Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector)
        {
            this.keySelector = keySelector;
        }

        bool IEqualityComparer.Equals(TSource a, TSource b)
        {
            if (a == null && b == null) return true;
            if (a == null || b == null) return false;

            return keySelector(a) == keySelector(b);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode(TSource obj)
        {
            return keySelector(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Which, as Richard says, is used like this:

```
var distinct = arr.Distinct(x => x.Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`

```
public class MyStructComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyStruct>
{
    public bool Equals(MyStruct x, MyStruct y)
    {
        return x.MyVal.Equals(y.MyVal);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyStruct obj)
    {
        return obj.MyVal.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

then

```
var distincts = myStructList.Distinct(new MyStructComparer());
```